# Problema de Roles con Spatie al usar dos bases de datos

Tags: laravel, spatie, laravel-permission

Tengo dos bases de datos en una misma aplicación Laravel, una hace la función de local `mysql` y la otra será externa `external` aunque actualmente tengo ambas en local para las pruebas.

Configuración en mi archivo `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=alerts
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION=external
DB_HOST_EXTERNAL=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_EXTERNAL=3306
DB_DATABASE_EXTERNAL=properties
DB_USERNAME_EXTERNAL=root
DB_PASSWORD_EXTERNAL=
```

El achivo `database.php` de la ruta `config/database.php` está configurado perfectamente.

El modelo `User` lo actualicé:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';
protected $table = 'users';
```

Ejecuto `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --database=mysql` para indicarle que se ejecute en `mysql` y lo hace correctamente, pero el problema está en los `Roles de Spatie`, me muestra el siguiente error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'properties.roles' doesn't exist
```

Trata de leerlos en la base de datos `Properties`

Pienso que una solución podría ser ubicar los Modelos de Spatie `Role y Permission` y hacer lo mismo que en el modelo `Users`

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';
```

Pero no sé donde se encuentran o como extenderlos.

Comment: Fíjate este hilo https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/697#issuecomment-643920515 . al final dice que no soporta definir la conexión en el paquete ya que puedes extender los modelos y definir la conexión en tu modelo. O sea te creas una clase que extienda de Permission y otra de Role, y usas esas para la relación con User

Comment: Gracias, siempre atento! Ya lo resolví ayer... Voy a publicar la solución!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo resolví extendiendo los Modelos

Permission

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission as SpatiePermission;

class Permission extends SpatiePermission
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
}
```

Role

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as SpatieRole;

class Role extends SpatieRole
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
}
```

Los guardé en el directorio `Models` y luego dentro de un subdirectorio llamado `Auth`

Configuré el archivo `config/permission.php` indicando las rutas de las clases

```
'permission' => App\Models\Auth\Permission::class,

'role' => App\Models\Auth\Role::class,
```

Y con eso bastó para solucionarlo.